# Inf and sup on $A=\left\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{10}) \in \mathbb R^{10}: \sum_{1 \le i<j \le 10} x_ix_j=45, x_1\ge0, x_2\ge 0,\dots, x_{10} \ge 0 \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $$A=\left\{ (x_1,x_2, \dots, x_{10}) \in \mathbb R^{10}: \sum_{1 \le i < j \le 10} x_ix_j=45, x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0, \dots, x_{10} \ge 0 \right\}$$ and let $f(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_{10})=x_1+x_2+\dots + x_{10}$.
> Find infimum and supremum of the function $f$ on the set $A$; indicate which of these is achieved.

The most mechanical solution seems to be the use of the method of Lagrange multipliers. But it will be a monotonous calculation, and I feel that it can be done in a more brilliant way. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: What is the function $f$?

Comment: @kimchilover $f(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_{10})=x_1+x_2+\dots + x_{10}$

Comment: See https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/NewtonMaclaurin.shtml
Also let $x_3=\dots=x_n=0$, what is the supremum with this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supremum is clearly $+\infty$.
For example, let $x_j=0$ for all $j\ge 3$.
Then the problem becomes maximizing $x_1+x_2$ subject to $x_1x_2=45$ and $x_1,x_2\ge 0$.
There always exists some $x_2$ satisfying the constraints for any $x_1$ arbitrarily large,
so the supremum is $+\infty$.

By using [Maclaurin's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality),
we have
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i}{10}\ge \left( \frac{\sum_{1\le i<j\le 10}x_ix_j}{45} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1
$$
and the equality is attained if and only if $x_i=x_j$ for all $i,j$.
The infimum is thus $10$, attained at $(x_1,\dots,x_{10})=(1,\dots,1)$.